# ZeroMQ Multiple TCP Connections

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, zeromq

I am currently using ZMQ to publish messages between a back-end server and a front-end web server. Sometimes the front-end doesn't appear to receive the messages I am sending.

Doing a quick netstat I can see the following:

```
  TCP    169.###.##.###:5557    169.###.##.###:53846   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    169.###.##.###:5557    169.###.##.###:53847   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    169.###.##.###:5557    169.###.##.###:53850   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    169.###.##.###:5557    169.###.##.###:53893   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    169.###.##.###:5557    169.###.##.###:53894   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    169.###.##.###:53846   169.###.##.###:5557    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    169.###.##.###:53847   169.###.##.###:5557    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    169.###.##.###:53850   169.###.##.###:5557    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    169.###.##.###:53893   169.###.##.###:5557    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    169.###.##.###:53894   169.###.##.###:5557    ESTABLISHED
```

I am running everything from localhost and this to me doesn't look so great as my subscriber has multiple connections to the same socket. Could someone confirm whether this is an issue or not? I have some code on my frontend that calls disconnect() but this doesn't seem to have made a difference to the number of open connections.

Comment: Can't help without code.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that your frontend is leaking socket references and that you actually have 5 sockets open to your backend.